# Как подключить Android к локальному серверу ноутбука?

Tags: android, linux, localhost

Всем привет, пишу веб сервер на локальном хосте в Linux Ubuntu на SparkJava. Параллельно пишу Android клиент для сайта. Как мне можно подключить Android к локальному серверу, чтобы в мобильном браузере страницы грузились как на ноутбуке? Я погуглил, но нашёл решения только в том случае, когда Android подключен к точке доступа ноутбука. В моём же случае ноутбук подключен к Android Wi-Fi.

ADB интерфейс настроен

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На ноутбуке в командной строке введите `ip a` это покажет сети к которым подключен ноут, сети `wi-fi` скорее всего будут в разделе `wlan0:` смотрите какой адрес присвоен ноуту, например у меня так:

```
inet 192.168.1.175/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global wlan0
```

Получили адрес ноута, теперь в приложении Android указываем к какому адресу обращаться, или просто пробуем зайти через браузер на устройстве по адресу `http://192.168.1.175` плюс порт на котором запущен сервер `:8080`

Comment: Огромное спасибо!

Comment: Кстати, интерфейс у меня wlan0. Проверил через `iwconfig`